# Work with thermodynamical equilibrium condition

Tags: thermodynamics, work, equilibrium

A thermodynamic system being in thermodynamic equilibrium
is characterized by the property that for every
thermodynamic potential $F$ which describes the system, its differential $dF$ is zero. Let consider for example the internal energy $U(S, V, N_i)$ for now. If the system is in thermodynamic equilibrium then

$$dU= \frac{\partial U}{\partial S}dS + 
\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}dV +
\sum_i^n \frac{\partial U}{\partial N_i}dN_i = TdS + 
pdV +
\sum_i^n \mu_i dN_i = 0 $$

Note that $\frac{\partial U}{\partial S} =T, 
\frac{\partial U}{\partial V} =p, 
\frac{\partial U}{\partial N_i} =\mu_i$.

Question: How this condition $dU$ helps "in practice" when one works with concrete systems and want to find out in which $(S_0, V_0, (N_i)_0)$ the system has its
"equilibrium"?

When I try to apply it I obtain something nonsensical and I want to understand which mistake I make here. Back to our condition $dU=0$ implies that $\frac{\partial U}{\partial S} =T, \frac{\partial U}{\partial V} =p, \frac{\partial U}{\partial N_i} =\mu_i$ should be all zero, because  $S, V $ and $N_i$ are independent variables, therefore the differentials $dS, dV$ and $dN_i$ as well. So I obtain $n+2$ conditions
$\frac{\partial U}{\partial S} =0, 
\frac{\partial U}{\partial V} =0, 
\frac{\partial U}{\partial N_i} =0$

But this not make any sense to me simply because this would imply that if the state is equilibrium state, then always its $T, p $ and $\mu$ are all zeroes. But certainly there are thermodynamical systems which are in equilibrium but their $T, p, \mu_i$ are not zero.

I'm confused now, what I'm doing wrong? could anybody explain to me how to "read"
and "work" with the condition $dU=0$ correctly? sorry, if my question is too easy for people with elementary knowledge on this topic but also after long search I nowhere found an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have been misled by ab incomplete statement of the equilibrium condition. The precise statement is that for a system at thermodynamic equilibrium **under the condition of a fixed set of thermodynamic variables**, the corresponding thermodynamic potential is **minimum with respect to any additional variable representing a possible internal constraint**.

In practice, this means that if you have an isolated system characterized by fixed values of entropy, volume, and number of molecules, its internal energy $U(S,V,N)$ at equilibrium is minimum with respect to any other variable different from those determining the thermodynamic state. For example, if the system is in a container and a fixed, impenetrable and insulating wall is separating subsystem $1$ from subsystem $2$, this is equivalent to have two separate subsystems  with energies $U_1(S_1,V_1,N_1)$ and $U_2(S_2,V_2,N_2)$. If the constraint on thermal insulation is relaxed, and heat can flow between the two subsystems varying $S_1$ and $S_2$ but  without  entropy production, $S_1+S_2=S$, then only one additional independent variable, say $S_1$,  represents the constraint. The vanishing of the first order variation of the total energy with respect to $S_1$
$$
\frac{\partial{U(S,V,N,S_1)}}{\partial{S_1}}=0,
$$
at fixed $S,V,N$, provides the condition for thermal equilibrium after removal of the constraint, i.e. the equality of the temperatures of the two subsystems.

Comment: Hello Giorgio, thank you for your answer. I thought a while about
it and came to following question:
Is that a sufficient or only a neccessary statement on 
thermodynamical equilibrium? Namely can this 
equilibrium condition be used to decide if our given
system in an equilibrium state?
What I'm principaly interested 
in is if this criterion can be applied on following
thought experiment:

Comment: Assume 
we have an isolated system about which we only know that it has fixed
macroparameters $S, V ,N$ and we can always measure $U$ 
(I purposly not wrote $U(S, V,N)$ because as far as I know
the internal energy can be only expressed as $U(S, V,N)$ if
the system already *is* in td equilibrium, but that's what we 
are going here to check; see my comment on it below in $**$). Before
we start we measure $U$. What we do now is we try to vary artificially all possible physical 
parameters of the system but with respect only one rule: 
everything what we do should *not* change $S, V, N$.

Comment: That is we 
can try to change the system in every way we want as far as
the rule is not violated. 
And when we do it 
we continuously measure $U$. Assume we are able somehow (that's
a thought experiment) to can out all possible manipulations
of this system which respect to rule not to change
$S, V, N$. If the minimal value of $U$ coinsides with 
$U$ at the beginning then our system was in equilibrium state.
Does this approach make sense?

Comment: Motivation: by the procedure in the thought experiment to change 
the system in all possible ways as far as $S, V, N$ not change
I intended to imitate the mathematical procedure to vary any
variable in the system different from $S, V, N$

Comment: Note on $**$: As far as I understand the ussue the function $U$ 
(or any other td potential)
exists always but the only case when it depends only on three
parameters (as here $S, V, N$) is only the case when the system is
in equilibrium. In case of non equilib $U$ in general should
exist but is too complicated (maybe depend on infinity
many parameters) to work with, right?

Comment: @EddyWa, In principle, what you are suggesting would be feasible. In practice, the case of non-equilibrium configurations seems to be quite difficult to maintain, if the condition $S=const$ hs to be verified. Moreover, ensuring that all possible processes have been taken into account is not trivial.

Comment: So as far as I understand you correctly in practice
this condition you wrote in your answer with 
$\frac{\partial{U(S,V,N,\alpha)}}{\partial \alpha)}=0$ 
(where $\alpha$ arbitrary constrain) can be only applied to the
case when we already **know** that the whole considered system is
in equilibrium state and the (only?) practical usage
of this criterion is to study 
the behavior of partial (!)
systems within the whole system by applying it as 
pure mathematical input every time we remove a constrain
(like a dividing wall etc.)?

Comment: That is qualitatively this condition gives
no **new** informations about
the whole system regarded as whole system only what happens between partial systems?

Comment: @EddyWa, it is not always confined to the case of partial systems. An important example of a different usage is a first-order phase transitions. They can be described introducing one-phase branches depending on the order parameter of each phase. The choice between a homogeneous one-phase or a phase-separated system is done, in a system described by $S,V,N$, by looking for the minimum of the internal energy. However, in that case, the minimum condition cannot be put in differential form, due to the nature of the transition.

Comment: And in mathematical terms the main obstruction to put the min conditition
in differential form is discontinuity, right?

Comment: But I think that conceptionally this hits exactly the important point 
of the original issue. To stress the problem I see here it suffice
to consider again the whole system with params $S, V, N$ 
beeing already in equilibrium state and within two partial systems
with parameters $S_1, V_1, N_1$ and $S_2, V_2, N_2$ beeing at beginning
separated by a wall (call it the initial constrain $\alpha$ = 
say size of gap when we open the wall, initially $\alpha_0=0$). 
But when we slowly push to wall
to the side during the process the system is the whole time
in a non equilibrium state,

Comment: so I'm quite confused why **during
this procedure** we can the internal energy consider naively as a "function"
$U(S, V, N, \alpha)$ which can be analyzed by analytical
methods (like taking derivatives etc). I thought that when a 
system is in a non equilibrium state (like in the case while
we continuously open the wall) the internal energy (or any other td
potential function) exist of course, but is highly unpredictable, but on the other hand our condition is settled by taking derivative of $U$
while the system is not in an equilibrim state.

Comment: It seems paradoxical 
to me to apply analytical methods to a function which during
non equilibrium state might be hard to control, eg not be differentiable
or can it be justified somehow?